# Function to generate biobliography/references

Tags: python, string

I am working on creating a simple function that would accept arguments for a journal/book and create a function that generates a bibliographic reference.

My attempt for now is inelegant.

```
def citation():
    title = input('Enter the title of the journal: ')
    authors = input('Enter the list authors: ')
    journal = input('Enter the name of the Journal: ')
    publicationdate = int(input('Enter the date of publication: '))
    volume = int(input('Enter the volume number: '))
    startendpage = input('Enter the start and end pages of the article: ')
    return print(authors, title, journal, publicationdate, volume, startendpage)
```

The end result should be something along these lines;

```
Bernoulli Jacob. "Analysis magni Problematis Isoperimetrici". Acta Eruditorum. 1701. Maji. 213–228.
```

A simplified version of the citation function that accepts the literature arguments and print out the reference may be more suitable perhaps

Comment: you can't return a print(). if you wanted a string you should just return it as an f-sting

Comment: return f"{autors}. {title}. {journal}. {publicationdate}. {volume} . {startendpage}

Answer (score 0):

Here's something a bit more elegant (but not by much):

```
def citation():
    info = ["journal title","author list","journal name","publication date","volume number","start/end pages"]
    info_str = ""
    for idx in range(len(info)):
        info_str += input("Enter the "+info[idx]) + ". "
    print(info_str)
citation()
```